# jquery dataTables plug in - how to get querystring values on server side?

Tags: jquery, lua, cgi, datatables

I have the following querystring that is being created by my dataTable:

```
http://testserver/cgi-bin/widget?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=1&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1431373301322
```

From my cgi script, i can extract values like "draw" and "start" by doing something like

```
local start = FORM.start
local draw = FORM.draw
```

But I need to know how to get at the other values.  In the F12 tool in FFox, I can see I have values like columns[1][data]:1  but I can't seem to get the right syntax to get at these values. In the query string I've shown you above, this value is sent/ posted as "columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1"

I've tried the following combinations:

```
--log(FORM.columns.1.data)
--log(FORM.columns[1][data])
--log(FORM.columns[1]['data'])
--log(FORM.columns['1']['data'])
```

I've also run some tests on the lua command line to make sure that I know how to access values stored in multidimensional arrays

```
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> mt = {}
> mt[1]={}
> mt[1]['data']=1
> print(mt[1].data)
1
> print(mt[1]['data'])
1
>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The querystring is [percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) since querystrings can't have e.g. brackets in them. You have to decode it before using it. [Here](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html) is an example of how to do that (toward the end of the page). The two methods:

```
function unescape (s)
  s = string.gsub(s, "+", " ")
  s = string.gsub(s, "%%(%x%x)", function (h)
        return string.char(tonumber(h, 16))
      end)
  return s
end
```

which is used by

```
cgi = {}
function decode (s)
  for name, value in string.gfind(s, "([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)") do
    name = unescape(name)
    value = unescape(value)
    cgi[name] = value
  end
end
```